# Ubuntu Software - why are the available app names not actually shown?

Tags: gnome-software

```
el_gallo_azul@W2600CR-850Pro:~$ lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
```

100% repeatable.

1. Start "Ubuntu Software"
2. Scroll down to "Categories"
3. Choose eg. "Internet"
4. Choose "Web Browser"

This results in
[image]

It looks like there are 14 available applications, but I can't see what the applications are called. If I click on the one of these rectangles with dots, nothing happens. This looks an awful lot like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

it's not a bug, it's a problem on your machine. When I repeat your steps I get:

[image: Ubuntu Software Web Browsers]

Did you have a new install or an upgrade from earlier version? Sorry for asking a question but I couldn't fit the screen shot into a comment.

```
┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
rick@dell:~$ uname -r
4.7.5-040705-generic
┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
rick@dell:~$ uname -a
Linux dell 4.7.5-040705-generic #201609240533 SMP Sat Sep 24 09:35:42 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
rick@dell:~$ lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
```

---

### Edit 1 - Reinstall Software Center

The logical first step (and easiest step) is to reinstall the Software Center with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

First command is a bonus to fix any dependency errors.

Comment: Yes I am on an upgrade from 14.04. When it ran, it seemed to be successful for the first time in my life. I thought hallelujah I won't have to spend hours or days configuring everything again, which I've had to do several times before, every time I've previously attempted to run a distribution upgrade and then ended up having to get my computer functioning again with a fresh installation. Sadly, it wouldn't be very surprising if I'm starting to unearth errors from the upgrade now.

Comment: `el_gallo_azul@W2600CR-850Pro:~$ uname -a
Linux W2600CR-850Pro 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
el_gallo_azul@W2600CR-850Pro:~$ lsb_release -rd
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release: 16.04
`

Comment: I updated the answer with something to try. I also upgraded from 14.04 and didn't have the error you have now.

Comment: Thanks. I already had `software-center` installed. so I added it to my Unity launcher immediately above `gnome-software`. There are now 2 launcher buttons with the same icon. I would love to add a screenshot here, but I've never figured out how to do it in a comment using "mini-Markdown formatting". `[link](http://example.com)` (or variations thereof) never seems to work.

Comment: You can put an Edit section in your question with the screen shot. I do that  all the time as new information pops up based on comments.